# Extracting the icons associate with the files and displaying in a ListView

Tags: listview, imagelist

I have a code issue in vb.NET that I have not been able to resolve for several days. Please be indulgent, I am not fluent in English, I am French! So my first piece of code fills the 3 columns of my listview while the second code extracts the icons from the files. But I can't match the two, I think my first code is incomplete! First code:

```
For Each file In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(Path)
            Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(FileIO.FileSystem.GetName(file))
            item.SubItems.Add(FileIO.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(file).Length & " octets")
            item.SubItems.Add(FileIO.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(file).CreationTime)
Next
```

Second code:

```
Private Sub ExtractAssociatedIconEx()

        ListView1.LargeImageList = ImageList1
        ListView1.SmallImageList = ImageList1

        Dim dirInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo
        Dim fileInfo As IO.FileInfo
        Dim exeIcon As System.Drawing.Icon

        dirInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(StrShortPath & "\Librairies\")

        For Each fileInfo In dirInfo.GetFiles

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileInfo.Extension) Then
                exeIcon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileInfo.FullName)
                If ImageList1.Images.ContainsKey(fileInfo.FullName) Then
                    ListView1.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.FullName)
                ElseIf Not exeIcon Is Nothing Then
                    ImageList1.Images.Add(fileInfo.FullName, exeIcon)
                    ListView1.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.FullName)
                Else
                    ListView1.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name)
                End If
            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```

I can't seem to link the two, and if the two work separately, they don't work together.
Thanks in advance. If you have another solution, I am obviously interested.
Regards,

Claude

PS: the second code comes from Stack Overflow, a little over six months, I came to find it. Thanks to its author.